# Thymeleaf Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, view, thymeleaf

Делаю приложение на `Spring Boot` с использованием `Thymeleaf`.
Есть сущность, которая в качестве поля содержит другую сущность. При попытке в форме `Thymeleaf`'а внедрить один объект в это поле другого получаю ошибку:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type ru.terentyev.EffectiveMobile.entities.Person for property executor; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value [ru.terentyev.EffectiveMobile.entities.Person@41544fe9]
```

А именно не получается полю `executor` объекта `task` присвоить в качестве значения объект сущности `Person`.

Вот форма:

```
<form th:method="PATCH" th:action="@{/tasks/edit}" th:object="${task}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:value="${task.id}"/>
    <p> Название: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"/></p>
    <p> Описание: <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"/></p>
    <p> Статус: <select th:field="*{status}">
                            <option th:each="statusT : ${T(ru.terentyev.EffectiveMobile.entities.Task.Status).values()}"
                                th:value="${statusT}" th:text="${statusT?.translation}"></option>
                        </select><br></p>
    <p> Приоритет: <select th:field="*{priority}">
                            <option th:each="priorityT : ${T(ru.terentyev.EffectiveMobile.entities.Task.Priority).values()}"
                                th:value="${priorityT}" th:text="${priorityT?.translation}"></option>
                        </select><br></p>
    <p> Исполнитель: <select th:field="*{executor}">
                            <option th:each="executorName : ${executors}"
                                th:value="${executorName}" th:text="${executorName.name}"></option>
                        </select><br></p>
                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
                            <span th:each="fieldError : ${#fields.allErrors()}">
                                <p th:text="${fieldError}"/>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="${task.author}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="${task.createdAt}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="${task.editedAt}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить"/>
    <br><br><br>
</form>
```

Вот сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Заголовок не может быть пустым")
    private String title;
    @NotBlank(message = "Описание не может быть пустым")
    private String description;
    @NotNull(message = "У задачи должен быть статус")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    @NotNull(message = "У задачи должен быть приоритет")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Priority priority;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person author;
    @NotNull(message = "У задачи должен быть исполнитель")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "executor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person executor;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
    private List<Comment> comments;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime editedAt;
    
    public Task(){}

// getters, settes
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Пароль должен содержать минимум 5 символов")
    private String password;
    private transient String passwordConfirm;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Task> createdTasks;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "executor")
    private List<Task> executableTasks;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

    
    public Person(){}

// getters, setters
```

Comment: Я же уже вроде разбирал подобную ошибку) Хотя, возможно, не вам тогда отвечал. Thymeleaf-форма не может вернуть ничего, кроме строки, в частности, объект класса `Person` она тоже вернуть не может. Но зато она отлично может возвращать айдишник, который Spring затем "сконвертирует" в объект, достав его по этому айди из БД. Соответственно, в `th:value` вы должны указывать айди пользователя.

Comment: Вряд ли мне. Спасибо.